# jupyter notebook: No module named PIL

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library, jupyter

I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and found `PIL==1.1.7 Pillow==5.3.0` installed.

But when I run `import PIL` in the jupyter notebook cell, I found the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

How to fix it? Any idea welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm, that your jupyter notebook runs in the same environment in which you run `pip freeze`?